# Optimizing Apache + PHP 5

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, dedicated-server

I have a dedicated Ubuntu box with a Plesk panel. My php files take a couple of seconds for the ttfb at random. Most requests are server lighting fast but after a couple of refreshes it waits very long even with empty files. I tried editing apache2.conf setting the ServerLimit etc. it responds better now but on a little load now I get 502 & 504 errors and not even static files served by Nginx are loading at that load.

My server config is:
- 2x Intel® Xeon® E5 2660 v3 (20 cores / 40 threads)
- 256 GB DDR4
- 3x500 GB SSD (6 Gbit/s)
- 750 Mbit/s Bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first I can hardly believe that config is what you have. That is some serious stuff man!! How many sites do you run on that?

Ok, so maybe a stupid suggestion, but I once had this problem and was because of the system was out of date. So my suggestion would be to deinstall apache and any other proxy's and just update your system.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After that reinstall all of your stuff and place your files back, but keep away from the config at first. If only you are accessing those files with some refreshes there should be no need to change anything (at first).

Comment: That updates only the sources.plist. After doing sudo apt-get update I tried installing Apache2 with apt-get to update it and it says that it is already the newest version. And I don't want to mess with Plesk very much. They are installed with Plesk.
Btw. I run somewhere around 50 - 60 websites on that server. :)

Comment: Lucky, you run more then just some refreshes on there ;) Do a full deinstall first `sudo apt-get --purge remove apache`. So you do the following 1. Fully remove apache 2. `sudo apt-get update` 3. Then install anything back and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

**Apache 2.4 optimizations**

I would suggest to:

1. **Comment useless logs in your httpd.conf** and/or it's dependencies. Each time a record is saved in the log, Apache asks your kernel to provide timestamp. If there are let's 4 logs that write the same record at 4 different places, it will ask your kernel 4 timestamps. On the other hand, be sure you don't need those logs before commenting them. I guess Plesk read Logs to monitor your system. Nevertheless, if you comment them and if the 502 and 503 disappear it means it is an issue with I/O with SSD (for instance a problem with driver)
2. Check if the directives in tag vhosts in tag directory are ok using the official apache website. you may have contradictory directives.
3. **Keepalive On**. this allows to send multiple http requests over one TCP connection. but i am almost sure it is already on.
4. Reduce timeout to 30 seconds.

---

less important:

**Remove languages from "Addlanguage" that you don't use**. For instance, remove AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw if you don't have content with taiwanese.

**Remove the AddCharset that you don't use**. same issue as for languages.

**Remove retro-compatibility to Internet Explorer 8** . Comment those lines with Mozilla/4 like  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

if you perform changes on httpd conf and dependencies use chattr +i yourconfigfile.conf to block any changes from plesk on those changes that you have made on those configuration files. you can remove it by doing chattr -i yourconffile.conf

the apache 2.4 config files should be ok out of the box regarding the different timers and number of persistent simultaneous connections. It does not have any consequences on performance. That's more plesk the problem. So, if plesks made changes to the original config files, try to see what they are.